# Set property of a class with obj-C runtime methods in Swift

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I have a class whose property value I'd like to set at runtime although there is not a signature to set it.

eg:

```
public class CBCentralManager : NSObject {
   public var state: CBCentralManagerState { get }
 ...
}
```

I want to be able to change this class's state at will because I'm creating a stub for unit tests.

stub:

```
class CBCentralManagerStub: CBCentralManager {
   func changeState(newState: CBCentralManagerState) {
      let val: NSValue = NSValue(&newState, withObjCType: &(CBCentralManagerState.rawValue))
      self.setValue(val, forKey:"state")
   }
}
```

In here, I was hoping to use obj-C runtime method,
`setValue:forKey` to accomplish this but I get the error:

> Error: '&' used with non-inout argument of type 'UnsafePointer'
>   (aka 'UnsafePointer<()>')

Is there any way to set the value of this class at runtime to manipulate this for testing?

Comment: You can't change the `state` of `CBCentralManager` it is a read-only property. If you want to perform testing like this you will need to mock the CBCentralManager class

Comment: You can change the value of an ivar with [`object_setInstanceVariable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/object_setInstanceVariable) but you case is more complicated because the property is readonly. That property can be a computed property, which may involve more than 1 ivar

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions - I was able to override the state variable in my stub and get what I needed.